# Azure pipelines bash tries to execute the variable instead of expanding

Tags: bash, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is really stupid but was driving me crazy for a couple of hours. I'm testing how to pass variables between Powershell and Bash. Relevant code:

```
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: 'pwsh_script'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $response = "6458ddcd4edd7b7f68bec10338d47b55d221e975"
              echo "latest (harcoded) commit: $response"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastCommit;isOutput=True]$response"


        - task: Bash@3
          name: 'bash_script1'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo $(LastCommit)
```

And I keep getting errors like:

> /d/a/_temp/b40e64e8-8b5f-42d4-8118-82e8cf8a28c2.sh: line 1: LastCommit: command not found

I tried with all kinds of quotes, double, simple, none. Nothing works.

Comment: `$(...)` is the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax, so yes it is looking for a **command** named LastCommit. For *parameter expansion*, you're looking for `echo "$LastCommit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
+              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastCommit;isOutput=True]$response"
-              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastCommit;]$response"
```

Turns out that the "isOutput" was breaking it, as it means you I was creating a multi-job output variable and trying to use it inside the same job.

From the official documentation:

> If you want to make a variable available to future jobs, you must mark it as an output variable by using isOutput=true. Then you can map it into future jobs by using the $[] syntax and including the step name that set the variable. Multi-job output variables only work for jobs in the same stage.
>
> To pass variables to jobs in different stages, use the stage dependencies syntax.

When you creating a multi-job output variable, you should assign the expression to a variable.
For example:

`myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]  # map in the variable`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `echo $(LastCommit)`

then you just need to remove `isOutput`

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastCommit]$response"
```

And with `isOutput` you need to reference via task name

```yaml
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: 'pwsh_script'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $response = "6458ddcd4edd7b7f68bec10338d47b55d221e975"
              echo "latest (harcoded) commit: $response"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastCommit;isOutput=True]$response"


        - task: Bash@3
          name: 'bash_script1'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo $(pwsh_script.LastCommit)
```